# Linux Headers not found for VMWare Player

Tags: kernel-modules, vmware

I recently installed debian 8 on my machine, which went fine. When I tried to install the vmware player 2.5.5-328052 the vmware software complains about not being able to find the linux headers matching my running kernel. `uname -r` yields `3.16.0-4-686-pae`.

So I installed the headers (and gcc) and here is how it looks:

```
olav@carina:~/Downloads$ ls -l /usr/src/
insgesamt 80024
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Feb 28 19:43 linux-config-3.16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     4096 Mär  1 10:40 linux-headers-3.16.0-4-686-pae
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     4096 Mär  1 10:40 linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       24 Nov 22 20:32 linux-kbuild-3.16 -> ../lib/linux-kbuild-3.16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 81928908 Jan 17 20:41 linux-source-3.16.tar.xz
```

But still, vmware does not find the headers.

What am I doing wrong? What precisely is vmware looking for?

Thank you, Olav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that, in some versions of the Linux kernel, the version.h file needed by the VMware Tools installer have been relocated from `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux` to `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux`, and the installer has not been updated to handle that.

The solution would be to create a symbolic link to version.h at the location where VMware Tools installer expects it.

```
ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/version.h
```

Comment: Hm, initially the symbolic link couldn't be created, because on my system there is no /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux folder. I created the folder manually and established the symlink, but it didn't help either.

Comment: The path to the kernel headers is: /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include

Comment: Yes, that folder is there. But in that folder there was no `linux` folder, which I created in order to do the symlink you recommended. All of which didn't render the vmware kernel module installer any happier.

Comment: Before downloading kernel source, install dpkg-dev, which contains a suite of development tools needed to build Debian source packages: aptitude install install dpkg-dev THEN aptitude install build-essential THEN aptitude install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

Comment: Still, no success. I "purged" all packeges I previously installed and did what you said: Install dpkg-dev, build-essential, and finally the headers. Directory `/usr/src` now holds two new folders (common and 686-pae), but the kernel module updater of vmware is still not happy. I double checked the kernel version and what the kernel module updater is mentioning. It is identical.
Does anybody know where precisely the kernel module updater is looking for the headers?

Comment: Possibly I am working with an outdated version of the vmware player. I need a 32bit version of it. Does anybody know where I could get a more recent one than version 2.5.5-328052?

Comment: https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=WKST-1004-LX&productId=362&rPId=7049

Comment: After creating this symlink, I ran bin/vmware-uninstall-tools.pl form the vmware-tools-distrib directory and re-ran vmware-install.pl.  The install automatically detected the headers path as /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include.  Thank you!